# How do I change and/or move a class that has been serialized?

Tags: c#, serialization, refactoring, settings

I've got a class in my project and I want to move and rename that class to somewhere else in the project's namespace. I tried simply moving it, but then the program won't deserialize any settings saved under `Properties.Settings.Default` for that setting. Is there a way I can move it without losing all of the user's settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [SerializationBinder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.serializationbinder.aspx) contains a solution for your problem.

From the MSDN documentation:

> Some users need to control which class
>   to load, either because the class has
>   moved between assemblies or a
>   different version of the class is
>   required on the server and client.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume your using Studio, have you tried dragging the class into a Class Diagram and renaming from there?  I find that Studio refactors accordingly from the Class Diagram.

Comment: The issue isn't that I can't rename the class in my code. I can do that no problem. It's when the Framework goes to deserialize the class from storage it can't find the original class it was serialized with.

Comment: Also, are the locations in which you are serializing and deserializing different? For instance, a class is serialized in an environment with Framework 1.1 and deserialized in an environment using Framework 2.0.

Comment: There's no specific error, it just doesn't deserialize the setting. Say I have version 3.0 of my product out and I have selected the `MyBadClassname` as the type for one of the properties. I decide to rename it to `DescriptiveClassname` and move it to the `MyProduct.Settings` namespace. If I do this, when I call `Properties.Settings.Upgrade()` the value for the property is an brand-new empty object instead of the object with data populated that was serialized before.

Comment: The location remains the same: `%userprofile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Company\Product` This location is selected automatically by the Framework.